# Data Validation for IP address in excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to add data validation for ip address in my cell. The Ip address should be from 0.0.0.0 to 256.256.256.256. To check valid Ip address i am trying to check following conditions:

```
1.there should be only three dots
2.length of digits should be from 4 to 12.
3.not any digit should be more than 256 or less than 0.
4.it should not take any blanks in between
```

I am trying through data>data validation>custom>formula>

```
1.=AND((LEN(C8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C8,".","")))=3,ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(C8,".","")+0))
2.=AND(LEN(C8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C8,".",""))=3,--LEFT(C8,FIND(".",C8)-1)<224,--LEFT(C8,FIND(".",C8)-1)>0,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(C8,"."," "),6,5)<256,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(C8,"."," "),15,7)<256,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(C8,"."," "),22,10)<256)
```

But my all conditions are not getting satisfied from it.

Please let me know how to add data validation for IP through data validation or conditional formatting.

Comment: What version of Excel?  MAC or Windows?

Comment: windows @RonRosenfeld

Comment: And the version? (eg 2016, O365, 2007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a custom validation rule, try:

```
=AND(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]"))=4,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))=3)
```

Where we use `FILTERXML` to split the string on dots and through `XPATH` we return those numeric elements ranging from 0-255. Then `COUNT` will check if there are just 4 elements returned.

The `AND` is there because we also need to ensure that there are only three dots.

Please do note that using `FILTERXML` requires Excel 2013 or higher (Excluding Excel Online or Mac).

Comment: I think you may want to change the `257` to `256` (Largest Octet is `FF`)

Comment: @sonali, add a third requirement to `AND`, for example: `LEN(A1)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, can you show me what you mean in the formula? Currently I set it as though it must be smaller than 257. Isn't the range required from 0-256?

Comment: No, the range required is 0-255.  The largest octet in an IP address is hex `FF` = dec `255`. Dec `256` would be hex `100` which is not a valid part of a legal IP address.

Comment: Ah right, I went with the requirements per OP. I'll edit the answer. @RonRosenfeld. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me! Had to array-enter it in my version of Excel (2019). Would probably use VBA for versions below 2013.

Comment: @JvdV I wanted to know if i want to use subnet with ip like 1.2.2.5/30 what condition i need to add for that?